# Parameter delta in Adam method

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe

I am using Adam method in caffe. It has a delta/epsilon tuning parameter (used to avoid divide by zero). In caffe, its default value is 1e-8. I can change it to 1e-6 or 1-e0. From tensorflow, I hear that this parameter will affect to performance of training, especially limited dataset.

> The default value of 1e-8 for epsilon might not be a good default in general. For example, when training an Inception network on ImageNet a current good choice is 1.0 or 0.1.

If anyone has experimented with changing this parameter, please give me some advice about the effect of this parameter on performance?

Comment: As far as I know, all these are rules of thumb. This means that these values will affect and depend on the data that you use as well as on the method that you implement. The best thing to do, is a grid search using a lot of values for the delta, and see the performance.

Comment: Each training process takes 1~2days, so grid search may take one month. So bad

Comment: where do you run the code ? On laptop ? Server ? Do you use all the cores ?

Comment: I used GPU TitanX with cudnn support. I am running in server

Comment: Do you need to run the training for the full 1-2 days before you have any information about what delta values are good?

Comment: Yes. Because my network coverage is so slow (50.000 iterations)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the update equation for Adam: epsilon is to prevent dividing by zero in the case that (the exponentially-decaying average of) the standard deviation of the gradients is zero.

Why would a low value of epsilon cause problems? Perhaps there are cases where some parameters settle to good values before others and having epsilon too low means those parameters get huge learning rates and get pushed away from those good values. I'd guess this would be more problematic in something like a resnet where a lot of the layers have little effect on a large portion of the examples.

On the other hand, setting epsilon higher both limits the parameter-wise learning rate effect and reduces all the learning rates, slowing down training. It's possible to find examples of higher values of epsilon helping simply because the learning rate was too high to begin with.